# move only uniq files from one directory to other

Tags: shell-script, ksh, file-copy, mv

I want to move files from directory A to directory B. But there are some conditions.

directory A structure:

```
a.txt_20170502 
b.txt_20170502
a.txt_20170507
asd.txt_20170509
asd.txt_20170522
```

So, I want to rename `a.txt_20170502` to `a.txt` and move that file to directory B, but if `a.txt` is  present in directory B, it will not move that file.

Example:

```
a.txt
asd.txt
```

This process continue until all the candidate files are moved from directory A to B.

I am confused how I can check if files are already in that directory,It will not move that file.

**Condition** :-
There is another script running in background which will fetching data from directory B.
So, if any files are present in directory B , it will be automatically copied mainframe server.

Comment: You use both `move` and `copy` seemingly interchangeably. Please clarify the question - do you want to move (cut and pase) or copy (copy and paste) the files? what happens to other files like a.txt_xxxx and a.txt_yyyy - which one gets renamed, by what order? which one remains in A?

Comment: @Dani_l I want to use move (cut and paste), And first a.txt_xxxx is renamed to a.txt  and copied to directory B than it will come to a.txt.bbbb, renamed it to a.txt  and check into the destination folder , If files are present there it will not move that file and move to the next one .

Comment: do files have any special characters like `_` before `.txt`

Comment: @MhdWissamAl-Roujoulah No

Comment: @Sagar2311 Should the file be renamed but left in `A` if it is already present in `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for file in A/*.txt_*; do
  newfile="B/${file##*/}"  # remove A path, add B path
  newfile="${newfile%_*}"  # remove trailing suffix

  if [[ ! -f "$newfile" ]]; then
    mv "$file" "$newfile"
  fi
done
```

This will iterate over all files in `A` that matches `*.txt_*`. It will construct a new file path by replacing the `A` path with the `B` path and strip the trailing `_xxxxxxxx` suffix from the filename.  If the new filename is not already present under `B`, the file will be moved there.

Answer (score -1):

You can test the existence with:

```
if [!-f B/a.txt]
then
  mv a.txt_20170502 B/a.txt
fi
```

You should replace `a.txt_20170502` and `a.txt` by the variables that you use in your script.

Comment: OP question states - `This process continue until all the files are copied from directory A to B.` Your solution DOES NOT, and CANNOT guarantee that.

Comment: @Dani_I The OP also says `I am confused how I can check if files are already in that directory`. Perhaps he can clarify what he is looking for. The testing or the continuous copying.

Comment: @Marco I want ot make it dynamic. not by giving file names.